# Android Apk which is downloaded programmatically from Google Drive, is not installing, says "Unable to parse package"

Tags: java, android, apk, android-install-apk

I'm working on sample project. I'm trying to download apk from Google drive (by sharable link) and trying to install an update to already existing application

This is my code to download and install the update:

```
class DownloadApkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2U-9Im6jS66dHFXLTFIX0JQbnM/view?usp=sharing");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();


            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String error =  "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/tcr_update.apk");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "doInBackground: "+e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Below code is for opening the application installer

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        File apkFile = new File("/sdcard/tcr_update.apk");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare the downloaded APK to the original (e.g., via `md5sum`). Is it the same? Beyond that, do not use hardcoded paths, and do not use `Uri.fromFile()` on Android 7.0+.

Comment: yes. im using Android 7. Then what should be used instead of Uri.fromile()

Comment: Download to internal storage, set up `FileProvider` to serve from there, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. The downside is that this only works on Android 7.0+; you will still need to use external storage and `Uri.fromFile()` for older devices.

Comment: actually, i tried on android 6.. it says same error "there was problem parsing the package"

Comment: even both the applications are same.. I installed the application through android studio and generated apk and put in google drive to get link.. Unable to understand why the package error? .... and also I am able to download and install apk from Google drive

Comment: @CommonsWare     anything Im missing?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: it is working now and above code is perfect to download and install..

Comment: the problem was this apk path url from google drive which was not downloadable

Comment: This is why I asked you, in the beginning, to compare the downloaded APK to the original (e.g., via `md5sum`). In your case, there was no downloaded APK, if I understand your resolution correctly.

Comment: apks are correct but the problem was I just used the url from drive(sharable link which open download page but doesn't download)